# How to check equality between 2 HashMap<Number, String>?

Tags: java, dictionary, bigdecimal, comparable

I would like to check equality between 2 `HashMap<Number,String>`.
My idea is converting each Number into BigDecimal with `new BigDecimal(number.toString())` and then check equality with `compareTo() == 0` instead of the basic `equals` that is used when comparing 2 Maps.

Who has a good implementation of this, or even better : a better idea ?

Comment: It depends how you define if both maps are *equals*. Should they have the same keys only, the same values only, the same key-value pair?

Comment: same key-value pair, in my case.

Comment: What about `memcmp`? I would test map1.getKeys() against map2.getKeys() and call it equal if they have the same keyset. Then again, maybe you want to test the values too.

Comment: The problem is : if you have as an entry (int 42, "abcd") and (BigDecimal 42, "abdc") it should be equals

Comment: 1: you can't do equals between Numbers. 2 : You should know to never do equals between 2 BigDecimal, since it is based on scale

Comment: A bit off tangent, but can you change the design of the `HashMap`? The current design gives you difficulty in handling the comparison between 2 Maps.

Comment: I was wondering if there is another possibility, but I agree the design complicates things. Unfortunately it is not mine so I can't change a lot.

Comment: @Shark - This is a Java question.  There's no such thing as `memcmp` in Java!

Comment: @Olivier: You have to formalize your definition of "equal" between two maps. What if map 1 contains the mappings [int 42 -> "foo"] and [long 42 -> "bar"] and map 2 contains the mappings [int 42 -> "bar"] and [long 42 -> "map"]. Are the maps equal? There are lot of other corner cases which are neither obvious nor specified by your description.

Comment: @StephenC `Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[])` ?

Comment: @Shark - that's nothing like "memcmp".  For a start, you can't just cast a reference to a `byte[]`.  The type system forbids it.  Java does not have "pointers" in the sense that you need for the "memcmp" approach to work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a lot like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147573); as pointed out in the comments it doesn't make a lot of sense to be comparing arbitrary `Number` objects; why not just make your maps `Map<BigDecimal, String>` and just always use `BigDecimal` directly ([normalized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20091723/113632) with [`stripTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--) if necessary)? Then you can just use standard `Map` equality. Consider stepping back and asking whether you really need the behavior you're describing in the first place.

Notably, [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) doesn't implement `Comparable`, which should be a pretty clear hint that you shouldn't try to compare arbitrary `Number` instances.

---

If that isn't an option for some reason, here's a reasonable implementation of the behavior you're describing.

```
private static BigDecimal toBigDecimal(Number n) {
  return n instanceof BigDecimal ? (BigDecimal)n : new BigDecimal(n.toString());
}

public static <V> boolean numberMapEquality(
    Map<Number, ? extends V> a, Map<Number, ? extends V> b) {
  if (a == b) return true;
  if (a.size() != b.size()) return false;

  // TreeMap uses .compareTo(), not .equals()
  TreeMap<BigDecimal, V> bdMap = new TreeMap<>();
  for (Entry<Number, ? extends V> e : a.entrySet()) {
    bdMap.put(toBigDecimal(e.getKey()), e.getValue());
  }

  if (bdMap.size() != a.size()) {
    // comment out if you don't care about this edge-case - but you should
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Multiple keys in 'a' normalize to the same value; " +
        "equality comparison is unsafe.");
  }

  // Taken from AbstractMap.equals()
  for (Entry<Number, ? extends V> e : b.entrySet()) {
    BigDecimal bdKey = toBigDecimal(e.getKey());
    V value = e.getValue();
    if (value == null) {
      if (!(bdMap.get(bdKey)==null && bdMap.containsKey(bdKey)))
        return false;
    } else {
      if (!value.equals(bdMap.get(bdKey)))
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Alternatively just copy both maps to `TreeMap<BigDecimal, V>` and call `.equals()`, but that requires copying both maps, whereas `numberMapEquality()` only needs to copy one, avoids any copying if they're not the same size, and detects key collisions.