# How do I check if a BigDecimal is in a Set or Map in a scale independent way?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

BigDecimal's `equals()` method compares scale too, so

```
new BigDecimal("0.2").equals(new BigDecimal("0.20")) // false
```

It's [contested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102083/why-is-bigdecimal-equals-specified-to-compare-both-value-and-scale-individually) why it behaves like that.

Now, suppose I have a `Set<BigDecimal>`, **how do I check if 0.2 is in that Set, scale independent?**

```
Set<BigDecimal> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new BigDecimal("0.20"));
...
if (set.contains(new BigDecimal("0.2")) { // Returns false, but should return true
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to use == in your first example?

Comment: @RichardTingle no. It's not the same instance, but it's also not equal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`contains()` will work as you want it to if you switch your `HashSet` to [a `TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

It is different from most sets as it will decide equality based on the `compareTo()` method as opposed to `equals()` and `hashCode()`:

> a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method

And since [`BigDecimal.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) compares without regard to scale, that's exactly what you want here.

**Alternatively** you could ensure that all elements in the `Set` are of the same, minimal scale, by always using [`stripTrailingZeros`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29) (*both* on `add()` and on `contains()`):

```
set.add(new BigDecimal("0.20").stripTrailingZeros());
...
if (set.contains(new BigDecimal("0.2").stripTrailingZeros()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Normalizing a `BigDecimal` is apt to be expensive.  It would likely be better to have an attempt to storing 123.400 search for 123.400 and--if not found--123.4.  If neither was found, create a new wrapper object and store it under both keys.  If only the latter was found, store under the former key a reference to the wrapper found under the latter.  Normalization is very expensive, so storing the same value multiple ways would be cheaper than having to normalize before every search.

Answer (score 0):

[HashSet#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method can't serve your requirement, it implicitly call `equals` method. You should iterate over `Set` and use `compareTo` method. If value is found than set a flag.

```
    Set<BigDecimal> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(new BigDecimal("0.20"));
    boolean found=false;
    for (BigDecimal bigDecimal : set) {
        if(bigDecimal.compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.2"))==0){
            System.out.println("Value is contain");
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found)// Use this flag for codition.
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the compareTo method of BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal("0.200").compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.2")) == 0; // Means they are equal.
```

From the JavaDoc

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified BigDecimal. Two BigDecimal objects that are equal in value but have a different scale (like 2.0 and 2.00) are considered equal by this method. This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators (<, ==, >, >=, !=, <=). The suggested idiom for performing these comparisons is: (x.compareTo(y) `<op>` 0), where `<op>` is one of the six comparison operators.

Comment: Would this work with a set however? Who's .contains method automatically calls .equals ()

Comment: Not with a hashset, like the other answer stated. The answer from Joachim Sauer seems to do the trick. But a TreeSet sees 0.200 and 0.2 as the same value (because it uses comparTo instead of equals). But I do think, that's what you want.